# Is it Possible to Place a Permanent ShellTile on the Start Screen

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, live-tile

I'm wondering if it is possible to leave out the Uri QueryString parameter so that when a user pins a tile, it may not link to the application. This would be for design reasons when pinning several ShellTiles onto the Start Screen. The user would of course have the option to delete the tile manually from the Start Screen or from a button within the app itself. It seems when trying this I am still taken to the application but a debug error also occurs.

An example of when I create the ShellTile is as follows

```
ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?" + Constants.Key + title, UriKind.Relative), LiveTile);
```

Can this be modified somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your secondary tile must have unique navigation URI. However you could navigate to some page that would immediately close itself. It is not the best solution but there isn't any better way.

For uniqueness just use `Guid`. You can close app in code with `Application.Current.Terminate()` for example.

Comment: Thanks, I determined the same solution, although I just randomly chose `DateTime` for no reason other than its the first thing I chose. It doesn't look good though and is confusing to the user. Accepting your answer though!